# AWS Lambda with C# not inserting record to Dynamodb

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am following this [example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ItemCRUDDotNetDocumentAPI.html) to insert a record into DynamoDB table.

Here is my code

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient _dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

var tableName = "AppUsers";
Table userTable = Table.LoadTable(_dynamoDB, tableName );


var item = new Document();
item["phone-number"] = "1234569";
item["email"] = "test@test.co";
var response = await userTable.PutItemAsync(item);
```

There are two issues with the sample that I [linked here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ItemCRUDDotNetDocumentAPI.html)

1. There is no `PutItem` method available on the `userTable` object as mentioned in the article, just only the `PutItemAsync` method which I am using.
2. When I run the code in AWS Lambda the code times out at the line `Table.LoadTable(_dynamoDB, tableName)`

What is wrong with this code and how do I fix it? I tested the same table using Python and it worked. I can insert into the table using the console as well so its not the table but just the way the C# code is written.

Answer (score 0):

1. [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_DocumentModel_Table_PutItem.htm) most definitely exists, ensure you're importing the credit namespace.
2. May be related to initialising the wrong package. But also check permissions and network connectivity to DynamoDB.

If you continue to use Async then you must also await the response, otherwise the Lambda will just quit and you may have undesired results.

Comment: I think since I am using core .net I can only use the async methods as mentioned here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MDynamoDBPutItemPutItemRequest.html

Comment: My Lambda is in a VPC. Do I need to do anything there like open up some ports or create an gateway endpoint?

Comment: It works when the lambda is not in the vpc. I created a gateway endpoint on the VPC and it doesn't work even then. Is there anything else that needs to be done ?

Comment: You need to await the result now. If it fails you have no idea why because Lambda quits before it can tell you.

Comment: gateway needed route tables setup correctly. that made it work finally. Code already had await.

Comment: When you say you tested it in python and it worked, you should really test in the same environment.

Comment: I had created another lambda function using Python, The difference was that new test function was not in a VPC.